# show latitude and longitude both from GPS and cellular network together

Tags: android

Is it possible to show latitude and longitude both from GPS and cellular network together. I am using Eclipse.

Comment: i want to do that latitude and longitude show together from both GPS and cellular network

Answer (score 0):

as I know, you can do that with calling requestLocationUpdate twice as two different providers

Comment: i did same but not work, i think u dont understand my question, i have 2 text view, one for GPS lat & lon and One for network lat & lon, i am calling  requestLocationUpdate twice as two different providers but at a time only shows one text view, but i want to show both gps and network text view

Answer (score 0):

requestLocationUpdate works on preferences. it gives first prefrerence to Network always.
but if your GPS is turned on , then it will give you a more precise result using GPS.

Answer (score 0):

See [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html).

There are methods for requesting location updates with the provider as an argument.

Method:

- [requestLocationUpdates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Providers:

- [LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#GPS_PROVIDER)
- [LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER)